# How do you broadcast a UDP datagram and receive the responses in Rust?

Tags: networking, rust, udp, ip

I'm trying to implement the VXI11 protocol in Rust (to communicate with instruments like oscilloscopes, power supplies, etc) and I'm successfully sending a broadcast UDP message, but not receiving the responses.  This is the code I use to set up the UDP socket:

```
    let socket:UdpSocket = UdpSocket::bind("0.0.0.0:0")?;
    socket.set_read_timeout(Some(Duration::new(5, 0)))?;
    socket.set_broadcast(true)?;
    socket.connect(("255.255.255.255", port))?;
    println!("Connected on port {}", port);
    println!("Broadcast: {:?}", socket.broadcast());
    println!("Timeout: {:?}", socket.read_timeout());
```

I've also tried "255.255.255.255:0" and "192.168.2.255:0" in the bind call with no luck.  This is the code I use to receive the responses.

```
    let call:Vec<u8> = self.packer.get_buf()?;
    println!("Sending call, {} bytes", call.len());
    match self.socket.send(&call) {
        Ok(n) => {
            if n != call.len() {
                return Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, "Sent the wrong number of bytes"))
            }
            else {
                // Do nothing because we sent the number of bytes we expected to send
            }
        },
        Err(e) => return Err(e),
    }

    println!("Awaiting responses...");   // self.recv_buff is a [u8; 8092]
    while let Ok((n, addr)) = self.socket.recv_from(&mut self.recv_buff) {
        println!("{} bytes response from {:?}", n, addr);
        // Remaining code not directly relevant to the question
    }
```

This is the STDOUT output:

```
Connected on port 111
Broadcast: Ok(true)
Timeout: Ok(Some(5s))
Sending call, 56 bytes
Awaiting responses...
```

I also know that the remote hosts are responding because I can see it in tcpdump.  However, the Rust code just isn't receiving the responses.  Anyone have any idea why this would be?

```
$ sudo tcpdump 'udp port 111'
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on wlo1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
11:00:54.094534 IP deathStar.51499 > 255.255.255.255.sunrpc: UDP, length 56
11:00:54.100199 IP 192.168.2.4.sunrpc > deathStar.51499: UDP, length 28
11:00:54.100755 IP 192.168.2.3.sunrpc > deathStar.51499: UDP, length 28
```

Comment: Using broadcast is last-century technology that has been basically deprecated, and it cannot be ported to IPv6 because there is no broadcast in IPv6. The modern way is to use multicast. See [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/65812/8499).

Comment: Yeah, my understanding is that VXI11 is an older protocol anyway and maybe whatever replaces it will deprecate UDP broadcast.  However, I still have the same problem.  I can see UDP packets in tcpdump being sent to a socket that I'm supposedly bound to and they aren't showing up.  Those transmissions being originally triggered by a UDP broadcast is another issue.

Comment: Yeah, that looks like it says something pretty similar to the answer I accepted below.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR** Remove the `UdpSocket::connect` call and then try again. It will work then.

It looks like [`UdpSocket::connect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.UdpSocket.html#method.connect) is the root cause. Based on the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.UdpSocket.html#method.connect), `UdpSocket::connect` should be used if the socket has to process data from the concrete remote address. If the remote address isn't known then you can avoid `connect` call at all. Without the `connect` call, the socket will receive data from any remote address.

```
let socket:UdpSocket = UdpSocket::bind("0.0.0.0:0")?;
socket.set_read_timeout(Some(Duration::new(5, 0)))?;
socket.set_broadcast(true)?;
println!("Connected on port {}", port);
println!("Broadcast: {:?}", socket.broadcast());
println!("Timeout: {:?}", socket.read_timeout());

let call:Vec<u8> = self.packer.get_buf()?;
println!("Sending call, {} bytes", call.len());
match self.socket.send(&call) {
    Ok(n) => {
        if n != call.len() {
            return Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, "Sent the wrong number of bytes"))
        }
        else {
            // Do nothing because we sent the number of bytes we expected to send
        }
    },
    Err(e) => return Err(e),
}

println!("Awaiting responses...");   // self.recv_buff is a [u8; 8092]
while let Ok((n, addr)) = self.socket.recv_from(&mut self.recv_buff) {
    println!("{} bytes response from {:?}", n, addr);
    // Remaining code not directly relevant to the question
}
```

Comment: This answer solved my problem with one small modification.  I needed to use self.socket.send_to(...) instead of self.socket.send(...).  Otherwise you get `Error: Os { code: 89, kind: Other, message: "Destination address required" }`

Comment: reproduced this (fixing typos, references to self etc in the code which doesn't compile as is). Most important to note is that I could only get it to work with the broadcast address "255.255.255.255", and NOT with "192.168.2.255". Did you get it to work with either/both?

Comment: Hi @andrew-mackenzie, I think it worth it to post link to your code there or even ask new question.

Comment: Happy to share the code. It’s here: https://github.com/andrewdavidmackenzie/simpdiscover I have also put a couple of questions I have into issues in that repo if anyone wants to chip-in